# Hierarchical Layout in mxGraph .Net

Tags: mxgraph

What is the best way to draw a hierarchical graph in mxGraph .Net? 
The JS version implements mxHierarchicalLayout, however, I failed to find similar functionality in the .Net version.

Comment: It doesn't have that layout.

Comment: I know... that is the reason for the question.
Do you know if there is a plan to port the rest of the layouts to the dot net version? Are there any 3rd party libs that can be used to build a layout?

Comment: It will not be ported. I don't know of a 3rd party libs, but even if you found one you'd have to write a bridge between the model formats.